# Create a new file with an updated suffix every time a new Logger is created with Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I would like to have Serilog write to a new file with an incremented suffix every time a new Logger is created.

For example:

- log_001.txt
- log_002.txt

Basically, I want the behavior posted by the OP on this github issue:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/issues/9

I want was the OP was trying to get rid of.

When I use this code below, only one file is generated even though the logger is `new`ed up multiple times:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\temp\testlog\log-{Date}.txt")
    .CreateLogger();

log.Debug("Created logger...");
```

Comment: That seems to be an unusual requirement for a logger. Perhaps a simple File.Open + Write Line is an alternative?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I suppose I could do that. Although, I'd really like to take advantage of some common logger features (like timestamp, context, error level, enrichment with properties, logging variables with json, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you check whether the `generated one file` contains `Created logger...`.

For `LoggerConfiguration`, its default `LogEventLevel` is `Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information` which means your `log.Debug("Created logger...");` code will not create log records.

I suggest you make a test with code below:

```
        var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\Windows\Temp\testlog\log-{Date}.txt")
                .CreateLogger();

        log.Debug("Created logger1...");

        var log1 = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\Windows\Temp\testlog\log-{Date}.txt", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .CreateLogger();

        log1.Debug("Created logger2...");
```

Above code will create two files, if you require the file name exactly like `log_001.txt` and `log_002.txt`, you need to implement your own `sink`, check this discussion [Filename without date #59](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/issues/59).